# NSToolbar with custom views

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Hi so I've got a problem that i can't really figure out what the cause is. I made an app so far that has a NSToolbar that has custom views in it so that you can switch between views on the toolbar (just like safari's preference window toolbar views). I was using CCodings tutorial on youtube but i have the problem of the views moving by themselves, for example i click on view 1 and when i click on view 2 view one changes and the view moves up so that you can only see half of when i put on the view, I'm using Xcode 6 and OS X 10.10 so i don't know if that would be one cause but i thank you in advance if you can help me, heres the MainWindowController.m file:

Also the views should be setup correctly

```
-(NSRect)newFrameForNewContentView:(NSView*)view {
    NSWindow *window = [self window];
    NSRect newFrameRect = [window frameRectForContentRect:[view frame]];
    NSRect oldFrameRect = [window frame];
    NSSize newSize = newFrameRect.size;
    NSSize oldSize = oldFrameRect.size;

    NSRect frame = [window frame];
    frame.size = newSize;
    frame.origin.y -= (newSize.height - oldSize.height);

    return frame;

}

-(NSView *)viewForTag:(int)tag {

    NSView *view = nil;
    switch (tag) {
    case 0:
    view = smallView;
    break;
    case 1:
    view = mediumView;
    break;
    case 2: default:
    view = largeView;
    break;

    }

    return view;

}

- (BOOL)validateToolbarItem:(NSToolbarItem *)item {

    if ([item tag] == currentViewTag) return NO;
    else return YES;
}

-(void)awakeFromNib {

    [[self window] setContentSize:[smallView frame].size];
    [[[self window] contentView] addSubview:smallView];
    [[[self window] contentView] setWantsLayer:YES];

}

-(IBAction)switchView:(id)sender {
    int tag = [sender tag];
    NSView *view = [self viewForTag:tag];
    NSView *previousView = [self viewForTag:currentViewTag];
    currentViewTag = tag;

    NSRect newFrame = [self newFrameForNewContentView:view];

    [NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];

    if ([[NSApp currentEvent] modifierFlags] & NSShiftKeyMask)
    [[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:1.0];

    [[[[self window] contentView] animator] replaceSubview:previousView with:view];
    [[[self window] animator] setFrame:newFrame display:YES];

    [NSAnimationContext endGrouping];


}
```

Comment: My guess is that you have the window's content view set to autoresize its subviews. During the animation, the subviews get repositioned or even resized due to the window resizing. The subviews are being swapped so it's not clear to me which would be affected by autoresizing, but one or the other almost certainly is, if not both. When you then swap back, you don't re-set the frame, so the subview gets put back into the window but at a different position.

Comment: thanks for the help but i tried to disable every autoresize subviews on all the custom views and that didn't help so I'm starting to think it might be a glitchy Xcode 6 or my OS thanks though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you also need to change NSWidnow frame apart from contenView. 
Also as for me for switching views by click events its better to use NSTabView.